# KaZip for C++Builder2009/Delphi

Tags: delphi, zip, delphi-2009, c++builder

I have download and install KaZip2.0 on C++Builder2009 (with little minor changes => only set type String to AnsiString). I have write:

```
KAZip1->FileName = "test.zip";
KAZip1->CreateZip("test.zip");
KAZip1->Active = true;
KAZip1->Entries->AddFile("pack\\text.txt","xxx.txt");
KAZip1->Active = false;
KAZip1->Close();
```

now he create a test.zip with included xxx.txt (59byte original, 21byte packed). I open the archiv in WinRAR successful and want open the xxx.txt, but WinRAR says file is corrupt. :(

What is wrong? Can somebody help me?

Extract not working, because file is corrupt?

```
KAZip1->FileName = "test.zip";
KAZip1->Active = true;
KAZip1->Entries->ExtractToFile("xxx.txt","zzz.txt");
KAZip1->Active = false;
KAZip1->Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

> with little minor changes => only set
>   type String to AnsiString

Use **RawByteString** instead of AnsiString.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how KaZip2.0 is implemented, but in general, to make a Delphi/C++ library that was designed without Unicode support in mind working properly you need to do two things:

- Replace all Char with AnsiChar and all string to AnsiString
- Replace all Win API calls with their Ansi variant, i.e. replace AWin32Function with AWin32FunctionA.

In Delphi < 2009, Char = AnsiChar, String = AnsiString, AWin32Function = AWin32FunctionA, but in Delphi >= 2009, by default, Char = WideChar, String = UnicodeString, AWin32Function = AWin32FunctionW.

Answer (score 0):

WinRAR could be simply failing to recognize the header. Try opening it in Windows or some other zip programs.

Answer (score 0):

> with little minor changes => only set
>   type String to AnsiString

That's doesn't work always right, it may compile but it doesn't mean it will work right in D2009 or CB2009, you need to show the places that you convert Strings to AnsiStrings, specially the code deal with : Buffers, Streams and I/O.

Answer (score 0):

It's not surprising that your code is wrong; KaZip has no documentation.

Proper code is:

```
//Create a new empty zip file
KAZip1->CreateZip("test.zip");

//Open our newly created zip file so we can add files to it
KAZIP1->Open("test.zip");

//Compress text.txt  into  xxx.txt
KAZip1->Entries->AddFile("pack\\text.txt","xxx.txt");

//Close the file stream 
KAZip1->Close();
```